# adding a new api to google cloud end points for java

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a sample google cloud end points project in eclipse using java.

I did it by using https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/quickstart-frameworks-java

and then imported the project to eclipse and converted as app engine project for standard envs.

All works fine till this point. However, I added a new API with java looks like below:

```
package photography.viks.ig;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiIssuer;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;

import photography.viks.ig.bean.MyBean;

@Api(
        name = "instaSmartTaggerSvc",
        version = "v1",
        namespace =
          @ApiNamespace(
            ownerDomain = "viks.photography",
            ownerName = "viks.photography",
            packagePath = ""
          ),
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        issuers = {
          @ApiIssuer(
            name = "firebase",
            issuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/instasmarttagger",
            jwksUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com")
        }
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
        )
    // [END echo_api_annotation]
public class InstaSmartTaggerSvc {
    @ApiMethod(name = "analyzeImage", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
      public MyBean analyzeImage() {
        return new MyBean("analysis done");
      }
}
```

and web.xml looks like

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  version="2.5">
    <!-- Wrap the backend with Endpoints Frameworks v2. -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.echo.Echo,photography.viks.ig.InstaSmartTaggerSvc</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Route API method requests to the backend. -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Add a filter that fetches the service config from service management. -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.api.control.ServiceManagementConfigFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- Add a filter that performs Endpoints logging and monitoring. -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.api.control.extensions.appengine.GoogleAppEngineControlFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>endpoints.projectId</param-name>
            <param-value>${endpoints.project.id}</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>endpoints.serviceName</param-name>
            <param-value>echo-api.endpoints.${endpoints.project.id}.cloud.goog</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The app deploys just fine to app engine. However, in the api explorer my newly added service is not visible

Comment: Were you able to get the sample app up and running with API Explorer working as expected? It'd be nice to isolate whether the problem is in the code or the configuration.

Comment: yes that works just fine. i dont see the 2nd one which i added coming up

Comment: Do you see any errors in your app logs when you try to access API explorer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate an OpenApi doc and deploy the file to the Google Cloud Platform. You can use the [com.google.endpoints.endpoints-framework](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.endpoints/endpoints-framework-tools) library to generate the file by calling openApiDocs.

Using Maven...

```
$ mvn clean package
$ mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs
```

The above commands will default to include the Api(s) defined in the "services" param from the EndpointsServlet defined in web.xml. The command will create the openapi-docs/openapi.json file under the "output" directory of your project.

To deploy the OpenApi doc, call...

```
$ gcloud endpoints services deploy OUTPUT_DIR/openapi-docs/openapi.json
```

Replacing OUTPUT_DIR with the actual "output" directory for your project. In my case this is the "target" directory.